# How to find T* if the product inner space is not explicitly

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

I have a little question. I was studying for my Linear Algebra test and I tryed the following problem:

> *If $T\in\mathcal{L}(K^n)$ is such that $T(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=(0,z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})$. Determine a formula for $T^*$.*

Well, I took the matrix representation of $T$ respect to canonical basis of $K^n$, $\left\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\right\}$. Then I considered it's transpose and the problem was "done" $\blacksquare$

I'm not sure of this because, yes, I know that matrix representation of $T^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $T$, but I don't have how to verify that $T^*$ is right by considering just the definition of $T^*$ because I don't have an explicit inner product defined. But yes, when I take some standard examples of inner products it works.

Comment: If you really want to verify this completely then you can just work out $(Tu,v)$ and $(u,T^*v)$ using the inner product axioms.

Comment: How and In what sense? I ask because inner product axioms will only help me to check if $<\ ,\ >$ is an inner product, not if I have an equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take $u=(u_1,\dots,u_n), v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ then
$$\begin{align*}
(Au,v)&=((0,u_1,\dots, u_{n-1}),(v_1,\dots v_n))\\
&=(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_ie_{i+1},(v_1,\dots,v_n))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_i(e_{i+1},(v_1,\dots,v_n))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_i(e_{i+1},\sum_{j=1}^nv_je_j)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_i\bar{v_j}(e_{i+1},e_j)
\end{align*}$$

Now just do the same thing (i.e. express as a linear combination of $(e_i,e_j)$) for $(u,A^*v)$ and verify that they are in fact equal.

Comment: Oh, I understand you now. Thank you =)!

Answer (score 0):

The inner product on $K^n$, by default, is the "dot-product".  That is, we take
$$
\langle(x_1,\dots,x_n),(y_1,\dots,y_n)\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\overline{y_k}
$$
It is only with respect to this inner product that the conjugate-transpose happens to give the adjoint.

Comment: Are you sure? as far I know it is because you have to orthonormal basis. The dot-product is the most important example of inner product in $K^n$ but it is not the inner product by default.

Comment: "You have to orthonormal basis"?  What does that mean?  Yes, the inner product on $K^n$ is, by default, the dot product.  At the very least, it is the inner product if and only if the canonical basis is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Im sorry, I wrote it wrong, I don't know why I did that misstake xD, haha. It was "you have a orthonormal basis".And yes, I was thinking about it after I did what user2520938 tell me about "to verify". I think you think it is by default cause it is related to the canonical basis $\left\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\right\}$. If you take another orthonormal basis the result will be distinct.